# error display in js

Tags: javascript

guys im typing a piece of java script code which is surely wrong,but im not receiving any error message which i should receive,can you please explain why error message is not shown to me?

js code is

```
document.write("num.toExponential() is " + num.toExponential()); 

alert("num.toExponential(4) is " + num.toExponential(4)); //displays 7.7123e+1

alert("num.toExponential(2) is " + num.toExponential(2)); //displays 7.71e+1

alert("77.1234.toExponential() is " + 77.1234.toExponential()); //displays 7.71234e+1

alert("77 .toExponential() is " + 77 .toExponential()); //displays 7.
```

this should display an error which it is not showing,
also output is not shown to me so there is error which itself isnt shown to me,
what should i do to see that error ?
if i change value of num to some number it works properly and shows me output .

Comment: Did you define `num`, as in `var num = 123;`? If I do so, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see Javascript errors, I suggest you use something like firebug, wich not only allows to see the errors but also to debug your code.

**In Chrome**, you just need to go to Tools > Development Tools. This will open a window on the lower side of your screen where you will se errors and be able to debug.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to vote up and accept when you choose an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript errors are not shown by default, as then you would get error message popping up everywhere surfing the web.

To see the Javascript errors you need to change the settings in the browser, or open up a console window that shows the errors.

For example:

#### In IE:

Open developer tools (F12) and go to the Console tab.

or:

Open Internet Options, go to Advanced and enable "Display a notification about every script error"

#### In Firefox:

Open Web Console (Ctrl+Shift+K)

or

Install a plugin like FireBug, open it and go to the Console tab.